# Controls in Listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm interesting, can I group some controls (image, 2-3 textboxes) in one element, and then push group of this elements in listbox? I'm trying to make a news reader of russian social network Vkontakte into Windwos Phone 7.

Each news has an image, text, and some other metadata. So I want to group all this info in one control and use it in listbox. 
I tryied to push a grid(which had an image and two textboxes) into listbox, but it throws XamlParseException.
Also, I need to get the content of theese textboxes and images from code. In grid I can use

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <src:Customers x:Key="customers"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: How does your model (data) look like? Is it 2 `strings` and an `Image`?

Comment: I have a class News, which has properties: string SoourseId, string Text , int Comments,int Likes, list of PhotoAttachment photoAttachment  list of VideoAttachment videoAttachments. Each model has a txtbox for SourseId, image for SourseId's photo, txtbox for text, txtboxes for likes and comments.

Comment: aslo, news can hold photos, dynamic count, but now I have to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

- A collection (`ObservableCollection<T>` recommended) of models (`News` in you case).
- A `ListBox`
- A `DataTemplate`

Example:

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                ...
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePropertyInModel}" ... />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextPropertyInModel}" ... />
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
ListBox1.ItemsSource = <collection of models>;
```

Instead of the `<Grid>` in `<DataTemplate>` you can use a `Custom Control` (`Templated Control`) or a `User Control` that you may already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an UserControl with the controls you want to use. With your ListBox you do something like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourItemsSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <my:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As ItemsSource of your ListBox you could use a ObservableCollection of News and through `DataContext="{Binding}"` you can bind to the News properties in your UserControl, e.g.:

```
<UserControl...>
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=photoAttachment}"/>
</UserControl>
```